# can we customize link detection in VSCODE's integrated terminal

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, terminal, hyperlink

VSCODE can auto-detect links in the integrated terminal as below.

[image: Web hyperlinks]

[image: Path hyperlinks]

Can it be customized?
Ex: All email IDs to be opened in the default mail app.

Answer (score 2):

**you will need to create extension that includes api call to vscode**

[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49), there is code snippet to show how to add custom `TerminalLinkProvider`:

```js
window.registerTerminalLinkProvider({
  provideTerminalLinks: (context, token) => {
    // Detect the first instance of the word "test" if it exists and linkify it
    const startIndex = (context.line as string).indexOf('test');
    if (startIndex === -1) {
      return [];
    }
    // Return an array of link results, this example only returns a single link
    return [
      {
        startIndex,
        length: 'test'.length,
        tooltip: 'Show a notification',
        // You can return data in this object to access inside handleTerminalLink
        data: 'Example data'
      }
    ];
  },
  handleTerminalLink: (link: any) => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Link activated (data = ${link.data})`);
  }
});
```

there is simple extension that use this [at github](https://github.com/MaximilianKoestler/vscode-xtext-links/blob/652af3fc3955b85945b9bcf0266aec835755a50a/src/extension.ts#L25)

and [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) for start your first extension.

you can build `visx` to install in every vscode manually or publish it.

credit - [Howto add a custom link provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64072251/howto-add-a-custom-link-provider/64671139#64671139)