# Howto add a custom link provider

Tags: terminal, configuration, pattern-matching

In the latest release of vscode (1__49), there is a code snippet on creating a new link provider. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49.   I can't seem to find a reference on where to apply this code.

```
window.registerTerminalLinkProvider({
  provideTerminalLinks: (context, token) => {
    // Detect the first instance of the word "test" if it exists and linkify it
    const startIndex = (context.line as string).indexOf('test');
    if (startIndex === -1) {
      return [];
    }
    // Return an array of link results, this example only returns a single link
    return [
      {
        startIndex,
        length: 'test'.length,
        tooltip: 'Show a notification',
        // You can return data in this object to access inside handleTerminalLink
        data: 'Example data'
      }
    ];
  },
  handleTerminalLink: (link: any) => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Link activated (data = ${link.data})`);
  }
});
```

What is the process for getting the editor to utilize this feature?

Answer (score 1):

### You will need to create a vscode extension that includes your code.

As it so happens, I have just set up a fresh extension that will use the `TerminalLinkProvider`. You can take a look at how the sample code integrates into a sample extension [on GitHub](https://github.com/MaximilianKoestler/vscode-xtext-links/blob/652af3fc3955b85945b9bcf0266aec835755a50a/src/extension.ts#L25).

A good place to start with your first extension is the [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).
After that, just add your code to the `activate(...)` function of your extension.

You can built your extension as a `.vsix` file and install it in any vscode instance you use, but if you think that your code might be of value to others, consider publishing it!